# Active Directory Query Application - Take 2

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

This is an update to my previous post about my [Active Directory Query Application](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129093/active-directory-query-application). I have made multiple modifications, and I request some feedback.

Summary: This program queries an active directory and writes either a list of the users or a list of the users with a list of the groups each user belongs to. The search is done in an Organizational Unit selected via a dropdown. Files are saved to .csv.

"Problems" I'd Appreciate Commentary On:

1. The front end (ActiveDirectoryTool) does a bit of what seems to be back end work, but if I move the work to the back end, I don't see how I can have the front end report progress.
2. On the same note, the front end's `backgroundWorker_DoWork` method is very complex, but aside from chopping it into separate methods for each of the cases, I don't know what to do.
3. It feels like I have a lot of duplicate code, but I don't see how to trim things down without losing functionality.

## ActiveDirectoryTool

```
using ActiveDirectoryTool.ActiveDirectoryToolBackend;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using static ActiveDirectoryTool.ActiveDirectoryToolBackend
    .ActiveDirectoryToolConstants;

namespace ActiveDirectoryTool
{
    public partial class ActiveDirectoryTool : Form
    {
        private ActiveDirectoryToolBackEnd backEnd;

        private Task currentTask;

        public ActiveDirectoryTool()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backEnd = new ActiveDirectoryToolBackEnd();
            UpdateDisplay();
        }

        private enum Task
        {
            PrintAllUsers,
            PrintAllUserGroups,
            PrintAllGroups,
            PrintAllComputers
        }
        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
            ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            var counts = (Tuple<int, int>)e.UserState;
            progressLabel.Text = counts.Item1 + ProgressLabelDivider
                + counts.Item2;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int percentComplete = 0;
                int currentCount = 0;
                switch (currentTask)
                {
                    case Task.PrintAllUsers:
                        var users = backEnd.GetUsers();
                        var filename = backEnd.AllUsersFilename;
                        backEnd.WriteHeaderToFile(filename, Header.User);
                        for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
                        {
                            currentCount = i + 1;
                            backEnd.WriteUserToFile(filename, users[i]);
                            percentComplete = currentCount * PercentMultiplier
                                / users.Count;
                            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentComplete,
                                new Tuple<int, int>(currentCount,
                                users.Count));
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrote all users to " + filename);
                        break;

                    case Task.PrintAllUserGroups:
                        users = backEnd.GetUsers();
                        filename = backEnd.AllUsersGroupsFilename;
                        backEnd.WriteHeaderToFile(filename, Header.UserGroup);
                        for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
                        {
                            currentCount = i + 1;
                            try
                            {
                                foreach (GroupPrincipal group in users[i]
                                    .GetGroups())
                                {
                                    backEnd.WriteUserGroupsToFile(filename,
                                        users[i], group);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception exc)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
                                continue;
                            }
                            percentComplete = currentCount * PercentMultiplier
                                / users.Count;
                            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentComplete,
                                new Tuple<int, int>(currentCount,
                                users.Count));
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrote all users' groups to "
                            + filename);
                        break;

                    // TODO
                    case Task.PrintAllGroups:
                        break;

                    // TODO
                    case Task.PrintAllComputers:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + exc.Message + "\n"
                    + exc.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
            RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            progressLabel.Text = "Awaiting task...";
            this.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void getAllUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformTask(Task.PrintAllUsers);
        }

        private void organizationalUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
            EventArgs e)
        {
            backEnd.Scope = backEnd.OrganizationalUnits[organizationalUnits
                .SelectedIndex];
        }

        private void PerformTask(Task task)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy
                && organizationalUnits.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                this.Enabled = false;
                currentTask = task;
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else if (organizationalUnits.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an Organizational Unit!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Currently performing an operation!");
            }
        }

        private void printAllComputers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformTask(Task.PrintAllComputers);
        }

        private void printAllGroups_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformTask(Task.PrintAllGroups);
        }

        private void printAllUserGroups_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformTask(Task.PrintAllUserGroups);
        }
        private void UpdateDisplay()
        {
            foreach (var organizationalUnit in backEnd.OrganizationalUnits)
            {
                string organizationalUnitDisplay = organizationalUnit
                    .Replace(",OU=Accounts,OU=Domtar,OU=DPP,DC=dnet,DC=domtar",
                    "")
                    .Replace("OU=", "");
                organizationalUnits.Items.Add(organizationalUnitDisplay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## ActiveDirectoryToolBackend

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.IO;

using static ActiveDirectoryTool.ActiveDirectoryToolBackend
    .ActiveDirectoryToolConstants;

namespace ActiveDirectoryTool.ActiveDirectoryToolBackend
{
    internal enum Header
    {
        User,
        Group,
        UserGroup,
        Computer
    }

    internal class ActiveDirectoryToolBackEnd
    {
        private string path = Path.Combine(Environment
            .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
            FolderName);

        public ActiveDirectoryToolBackEnd()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        public string AllUsersFilename
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.Combine(path, GenerateFilename(FilenameUsers));
            }
        }

        public string AllUsersGroupsFilename
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.Combine(path,
                    GenerateFilename(FilenameUserGroups));
            }
        }

        public List<string> OrganizationalUnits
        {
            get
            {
                var organizationalUnits = new List<string>();
                DirectoryEntry userRoot = new DirectoryEntry(
                    DefaultUserOrganizationalUnitsRoot);
                var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(userRoot);
                searcher.Filter = DirectorySearcherFilterOrganizationalUnits;
                searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
                foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    string resultString = result.Path.Replace(LdapPrefix,
                        String.Empty);
                    organizationalUnits.Add(resultString);
                }
                return organizationalUnits;
            }
        }

        public String Scope { get; set; }

        public List<UserPrincipal> GetUsers()
        {
            var users = new List<UserPrincipal>();
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(
                GetPrincipalContext())))
            {
                foreach (UserPrincipal user in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    users.Add(user);
                }
            }
            return users;
        }

        public void WriteHeaderToFile(string filename, Header header)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(CommaSeparatedValuesSeparatorSemicolon);
                switch (header)
                {
                    case Header.User:
                        writer.WriteLine(HeaderUser);
                        break;

                    case Header.Group:
                        writer.WriteLine(HeaderGroup);
                        break;

                    case Header.UserGroup:
                        writer.WriteLine(HeaderUserGroup);
                        break;

                    case Header.Computer:
                        writer.WriteLine(HeaderComputer);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteUserGroupsToFile(string filename, UserPrincipal user,
            GroupPrincipal group)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(UserGroupAsString(user, group));
            }
        }

        public void WriteUserToFile(string filename, UserPrincipal user)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(UserAsString(user));
            }
        }
        private string ComputerAsString(ComputerPrincipal computer)
        {
            return String.Join(
                Char.ToString(Tab),
                computer.Name);
        }

        private string GenerateFilename(string fileType)
        {
            return fileType + Hyphen + DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat)
                + DefaultExtension;
        }

        private PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext()
        {
            return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain,
                Scope);
        }

        private string GroupAsString(GroupPrincipal group)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = group.GetUnderlyingObject() as
                DirectoryEntry;
            string manager = (string)entry.Properties[PropertyManager].Value;
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(manager))
            {
                manager = PropertyNone;
            }
            return String.Join(
                Char.ToString(Tab),
                group.SamAccountName,
                manager,
                group.Description,
                group.DistinguishedName);
        }

        private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
        {
            if (de.NativeGuid == null) return false;

            int flags = (int)de.Properties[PropertyUserAccountControl].Value;

            return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
        }

        private string UserAsString(UserPrincipal user)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as
                DirectoryEntry;
            return string.Join(
                Char.ToString(Semicolon),
                user.Surname,
                user.GivenName,
                user.DisplayName,
                user.SamAccountName,
                IsActive(entry).ToString(),
                user.IsAccountLockedOut().ToString(),
                user.Description,
                user.HomeDrive,
                user.HomeDirectory,
                user.ScriptPath,
                user.EmailAddress,
                (string)entry.Properties[PropertyStreetAddress].Value,
                (string)entry.Properties[PropertyCity].Value,
                (string)entry.Properties[PropertyState].Value,
                user.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                user.DistinguishedName);
        }

        private string UserGroupAsString(UserPrincipal user,
            GroupPrincipal group)
        {
            return String.Join(
                Char.ToString(Semicolon),
                user.SamAccountName,
                group.SamAccountName,
                user.Name,
                user.DistinguishedName);
        }
    }
}
```

## ActiveDirectoryToolConstants

```
namespace ActiveDirectoryTool.ActiveDirectoryToolBackend
{
    internal static class ActiveDirectoryToolConstants
    {
        public const char Comma = ',';
        public const char Hyphen = '-';
        public const char Quote = '"';
        public const char Semicolon = ';';
        public const char Tab = '\t';
        public const int PercentMultiplier = 100;
        public const string CommaSeparatedValuesExtension = ".csv";
        public const string CommaSeparatedValuesSeparatorSemicolon = "sep=;";
        public const string DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmss";
        public const string DefaultExtension = CommaSeparatedValuesExtension;
        public const string DefaultUserOrganizationalUnitsRoot
            = "LDAP://OU=Accounts,OU=Domtar,OU=DPP,DC=dnet,DC=domtar";
        public const string DirectorySearcherFilterOrganizationalUnits
            = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
        public const string Domain = "dnet.domtar";
        public const string FilenameComputers = "Computers";
        public const string FilenameGroups = "Groups";
        public const string FilenameUserGroups = "UserGroups";
        public const string FilenameUsers = "Users";
        public const string FolderName = "ActiveDirectoryTool";
        public const string HeaderComputer = "Name";
        public const string HeaderGroup =
            "Group Name;Group ID;Managed By;Description;Distinguished Name";
        public const string HeaderUser
            = "Last;First;Display Name;ID;Active;Locked;Description;"
            + "Home Drive;Home Folder;Login Script;Email;Street;City;State;"
            + "Phone;Distinguished Name";
        public const string HeaderUserGroup
            = "User ID;Group;User Full Name;User Distinguished Name";
        public const string LdapPrefix = "LDAP://";
        public const string PlainTextExtension = ".txt";
        public const string ProgressLabelDivider = " of ";
        public const string PropertyCity = "l";
        public const string PropertyManager = "managedBy";
        public const string PropertyNone = "none";
        public const string PropertyState = "st";
        public const string PropertyStreetAddress = "streetAddress";
        public const string PropertyUserAccountControl = "userAccountControl";
        public const string TabSeparatedValuesExtension = ".tsv";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your backgroundWorker is fiddling with UI elements, although the only thing he does is to show
a `MessageBox`. I do not know if this is safe or not, but I will be consider to be unsafe on my review.

BackgroundWorker died long ago since TPL - Task Parallel Library appeared.
With `TPL` you can do **everything** you used to do with the old backgroundWorker and even in a neater way.

Instead of having that `Task` enum, you will have Methods that return exactly a `Task` object (this is marvellous I know).
That task will do exactly what a `case` statement is doing at this moment. Plus when the operation ends
in will also show the message on the UI thread instead of background thread like your `backgroundWorker_DoWork`
is doing at the moment.

But optimally you would change all your tasks so they would return a common type, that you could use to do the things
you wanted (show messages, updates labels or other controls...)

Tasks *per se* do not report progress but what we can do is to implement the interface 
`IProgress` on our form and call the `Report` method whenever needed.
Talking about reporting, one thing that annoyed me the most is that you didn't define a class to specify that data that
you want to report.
If you did that you could realize that Percentage could be a calculated read-only Property.

```
public partial class ActiveDirectoryTool : Form, 
IProgress<ActiveDirectoryTool.ProgressReport>
{
    public class ProgressReport
    {
        public int Percentage { get { return CurrentCount / Total; } }
        public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }

    private ActiveDirectoryToolBackEnd backEnd;
    private Task PrintAllUsers ()=> Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var users = backEnd.GetUsers();
        var filename = backEnd.AllUsersFilename;
        backEnd.WriteHeaderToFile(filename, Header.User);
        for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
        {
            backEnd.WriteUserToFile(filename, users[i]);
            this.Report(new ProgressReport()
            {
                Total = users.Count,
                CurrentCount = i + 1
            });
        };
        return filename;
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrote all users to " + t.Result);
    }, 
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
    private Task PrintAllUserGroups() => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var users = backEnd.GetUsers();
        var filename = backEnd.AllUsersGroupsFilename;
        backEnd.WriteHeaderToFile(filename, Header.UserGroup);
        for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (GroupPrincipal group in users[i].GetGroups())
                {
                    backEnd.WriteUserGroupsToFile(filename,
                        users[i], group);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
                continue;
            }
            this.Report(new ProgressReport()
            {
                Total = users.Count,
                CurrentCount = i + 1
            });
        }
        return filename;
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrote all users' groups to " + t.Result);
    },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
    private Task PrintAllGroups() => Task.Run(() =>
    {

    });
    private Task PrintAllComputers() => Task.Run(() =>
    {

    });

    private async void getAllUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PerformTask(PrintAllUsers());
    }

    private void organizationalUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        backEnd.Scope = backEnd.OrganizationalUnits[organizationalUnits
            .SelectedIndex];
    }

    private async Task PerformTask(Task task)
    {
        if (organizationalUnits.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            this.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + exc.Message + "\n"
                    + exc.StackTrace);
            }

            //this is what you would do on complete
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            progressLabel.Text = "Awaiting task...";
            this.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (organizationalUnits.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an Organizational Unit!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Currently performing an operation!");
        }
    }

    private async void printAllComputers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PerformTask(PrintAllComputers());
    }

    private async void printAllGroups_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PerformTask(PrintAllGroups());
    }

    private async void printAllUserGroups_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PerformTask(PrintAllUserGroups());
    }
    private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        foreach (var organizationalUnit in backEnd.OrganizationalUnits)
        {
            string organizationalUnitDisplay = organizationalUnit
                .Replace(",OU=Accounts,OU=Domtar,OU=DPP,DC=dnet,DC=domtar",
                "")
                .Replace("OU=", "");
            organizationalUnits.Items.Add(organizationalUnitDisplay);
        }
    }

    public void Report(ProgressReport value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((Action) (() => Report(value)));
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar.Value = value.Percentage;
            progressLabel.Text = value.CurrentCount + ProgressLabelDivider
                + value.Total;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `if (InvokeRequired)` block in the `Report` method do?

Comment: @michaelbmorris The `Report` method may be invoked on a thread of the thread pool, because is being called inside a task. To make sure we update the UI on the UI thread then we need to check `InvokeRequired`. `InvokeRequired` will be true if the current thread is not the UI thread. The same strategy could be used to show the MessageBox